# How to store user photo in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm wondering what is proper way to store users avatar/photo/Image from FirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().
My first idea was simple, **store URL** to this images as normal String, and It would be great if not the fact that facebook URLs expires.
So my second idea was to fetch these images and **store as Base64** String, but then I got to my third idea which is **Firebase Storage**, but I'm wondering if it is too slow to store so small and dynamic content as users avatars.

Comment: There is no reason to consider profile pictures "too small" to store them in Firebase Storage. Do consider however how you want your app to respond when the user updates their profile picture. They may not like it if your app keeps showing their old profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store it in Firebase Storage or the Realtime Database, just download it directly from the URL and cache it locally. No reason to store the same thing twice :)

Comment: as I said "It would be great if not the fact that facebook URLs expires"

Comment: I believe Mike suggestion is clever. It brings DRY, don't repeat yourself, with fastness - the cache storage. In the near term, abstract concepts like DRY means "nothing"; they became great friends a year or two from now, when you would need to sync firebase profile photos with actual profile photos. (Low) Maintenance is the new gold. When cache expires or the URL photo changes, your app would, ideally, update the cache with  the profile photo. All under the hood. I'll stick with this suggestion in my personal same issue, thanks Mike and thanks stasbar for the perfect question!